# Calibrating Camera: Multiple ways to obtain the scaling factor

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision

I am trying to obtain a mapping from 2D coordinates in image to 2D coordinates in the world(Planar object and hence Z = 0). I have obtained the intrinsic matrix and the extrinsic matrix as per the OpenCV documentation:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html

Now, I am trying to compute 's', the scaling factor:

[image]

I can solve any of the three equations to obtain 's', since I know at least one corresponding 2D-3D pair(Z = 0). But, each equation gives me a different value of 's'. Also, this value of 's' gives me the wrong mapping for other 2D-3D pairs.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: What equations do you mean when you say "I can solve any of the three equations to obtain 's'"?

Comment: Like I tried solving for 's' by substituting a 2D point (x,y) for which I knew the corresponding 3D point(X,Y,0) before hand. Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021733/obtaining-world-coordinates-of-an-object-from-its-image-coordinates

Comment: Are you sure you have a reasonable extrinsic and intrinsic matrix?